# Finding the point Intersection of tangents using complex numbers

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, circles

Let $P$ be a point outside the unit circle centered at $O$ in the Argand plane. Tangents are drawn to the circle at points $A(a)$ and $B(b)$ where $a,b\in\mathbb C$. Find point $P$ in terms of $a,b$? (Source used: EGMO)

**Answer:**
$$\frac{2ab}{a+b}\ \text{or}\ \frac{2}{\overline a+\overline b}$$ (bar representing conjugate)

---

Let $m =\frac{a+b}{2}$ (midpoint of $a$ and $b$). $\triangle OMA$ and $\triangle OAP$ are similar triangles then why cannot we use the similarity theorem for complex numbers. (If ABC ,XYZ are similar then $\frac{y-x}{z-x}=\frac{b-a}{c-a}$ to solve for $P$?) using this approach would yield $\frac{m}{a}= \frac{a}{p}, p=\frac{2a^2}{a+b}$ instead of $\frac{2ab}{a+b}$.

Another Question: The book said that $OM\cdot OP=1$ thus $(|m|\cdot|p|)=1$ but then it said that $\overline m\cdot p=1$, why did it use the conjugate of the midpoint instead of the midpoint itself?

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

1. For the similar triangles, the corresponding side **lengths** are proportional. In complex numbers, the length of segment joining $z_1$ and $z_2$ is $|z_1-z_2|$ and not $z_1-z_2$ which will be a vector and need not be proportional to the side vector of other triangle. So, in your case, it should be $$\frac{|y-x|}{|z-x|}=\frac{|b-a|}{|c-a|}$$
2. Since, $|z_1|=|\overline z_1|$, you can write $$|m|\cdot|p|=1=|\overline m|\cdot|p|$$ where $m,p\in\mathbb C$. But, it doesn't imply that $m\cdot p=1$. It is true only $m, p$ lie on real axis i.e. $z=|z|$.

---

**Solution:** The equation of line in Argand plane passing through $z_1, z_2$ is given by $$z(\overline z_1-\overline z_2)-\overline z(z_1-z_2)+z_1\overline z_2-\overline z_1z_2=0$$
So, the equation of line joining origin and $a$ will be $z\overline a-\overline za=0$.

Since, the tangent at $a$ is perpendicular to this line, its equation will be $$z\overline a+\overline za+\lambda=0$$ where $b$ is unknown. Now, $a$ lies on the tangent and we get $\lambda=-2$, given that $a\overline a=|a|^2=1$.

Similarly, you get tangent at $b$ as $$z\overline b+\overline zb=2$$

Solving these two equations for $z$, we get $$z=\frac{2ab}{a+b}=\frac{2}{\overline a+\overline b}$$